# Deploying Reactjs and PHP application together on Nginx at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx, devops, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run reactjs application and PHP application together on Nginx.
Reactjs application runs well, but I am unable to run PHP application.
I have added two server blocks for both the applications but unable to run PHP app which is actually my api/service for react js app.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Here is my nginx configuration for react js application:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html/qurancom-reactjs;        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name 3.16.130.108;
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
                                                                                                                                                                                          }
```

and here are my php app nginx server block configurations:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/quran-app-services/api;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 3.16.130.108;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your nginx configuration files ?

Comment: sure, let me share

Comment: @GrenierJ sorry for some delay, I have just added my reactjs configuration,

Comment: You used the same sever_name and port for the two serer, so Nginx take the first that match ( react).

I suggest you use another port for your react application (like 443 for HTTPS), 

Or change Server_name for one of your server ( and call it with this servername)